# How to convert columns into rows in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Please help me to understand, how to convert columns to rows in MS Access. I have the below table, I would like to convert as the below result table.

```
NoOf_A NoOf_B NoOf_C NoOf_D
200    300    400    500
```

Result Table:

```
Type_OfCValue  Total
NoOf_A          200  
NoOf_B          300
NoOf_C          400
NoOf_D          500
```

Answer (score -1):

you don't really convert columns to rows in the tables as they represent different concepts (column=structure, row=data).

What you need is a crosstab query. Check the link from excellent Allen Browne's site:
[Crosstab queries](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-67.html)

You can use a SELECT query first. Use that as source to your Crosstab query.